# Recommended build for getting Java native debug symbols

Tags: java, gdb, debug-symbols

The common know-how for inspecting the native code running within the JVM seems to be to install debuginfo rpm that comes with the .debug symbols for all the binaries in the associated JDK rpm.

I have used the flag --with-native-debug-symbols=external to generate the JDK8 rpms which does not seem to provide the required debug symbols.

Build generated --with-native-debug-symbols=internal however seems to work.

Which is build option allows the best performance AND provides the native debug symbols?